# How multi purpose search works with Searchkick?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, nginx

I'm looking to understand how a multi purpose search works,

for exemple i'm looking to search cell phone and the left menu return electronics related categories

and if i decide in the same search find shoes and the left menu return clothes related categories

like the amazon or Walmart, someone know how this shift of sections works in the same search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want your UI to react to choices users make, one choice leading to another choice.

A common solution to this is to write some JSON endpoints in your application in Ruby, PHP, or whatever you're using while leveraging jQuery's AJAX functionality.

You would write some JavaScript with the jQuery library included to watch for what the user does and call the backend for what the UI should do next.

Note that you can accomplish this in plain old JavaScript, but people tend to use jQuery for smaller one-offs.  Or, you could decouple your backend from the frontend completely by turning the server side code into a JSON API and use a frontend framework like React or Angular2 to consume the backend.

It sounds like your best bet is to give jQuery's AJAX stuff a try though.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you're using Ruby:  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

**Edit to add more info**

Before I answer that, let me note that jQuery is a library for JavaScript written in JavaScript.  It just makes JavaScript nicer to deal with, especially when you're wanting to do some API calls like this.

JavaScript can watch and react to anything a user does in your app.  If you want to say hi when they click a button, then you would do something like this

```
<button id="the-button">Say Hi</button>

<script>
$( "#the-button" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Hi!" );
});
</script>
```

AJAX can be used just like this "on click" functionality.

If you want to react to something the user typed into a search field, you might use the `.change` method to fire off the AJAX call the same way the `.click` method says `alert(hi)`:  https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: thank you Charlie, i started to understand this. so is a ajax reaction of the typed words in this case?

Comment: Right.  You might use jQuery's `.change` method to trigger the AJAX call: https://api.jquery.com/change/